Divide the y-axis into small differences in the Plot of three functions to show the difference between the curves functions
How can the y-axis be divided into small differences in the graph of three functions to show the difference.
Plot[{4 E^(-8 t) - 18 E^(-7 t) + 27 E^(-6 t) - 10 E^(-5 t) - 
   9 E^(-4 t) + 4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t), 
  2 E^(-8 t) - 10 E^(-7 t) + 15 E^(-6 t) - 2 E^(-5 t) - 11 E^(-4 t) + 
   4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t), 
  6 E^(-8 t) - 30 E^(-7 t) + 55 E^(-6 t) - 42 E^(-5 t) + 9 E^(-4 t) + 
   3 E^(-2 t)}, {t, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Blue}, Green}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"f1", "f2", "f3"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.81, 0.81}]]

The drawing result does not show the difference. I want it to be more accurate

For example, I want the y-axis to be divided into y={0,0.05,0.10,0.15,...,1} to show the clear difference between the curves of each function.
Thanks for the help.

I have had to show differences many times for model validations.  I normally just add a second plot below the main one where I subtract the signals/functions being compared. Would this approach be useful in your situation?

@GustavoDelfino Can you please explain this with an answer?

OK, but not right now (no time). I also have so code to add a magnifier glass that will open figure full screen and hooks into DragZoomShow to really let you magnify the differences.

You could maybe add the difference plot as an Inset also like this

Here's a simple way, which I would do first and then refine to a presentation-worthy image: Plot[{4 E^(-8 t) - 18 E^(-7 t) + 27 E^(-6 t) - 10 E^(-5 t) - 9 E^(-4 t) + 4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t), 2 E^(-8 t) - 10 E^(-7 t) + 15 E^(-6 t) - 2 E^(-5 t) - 11 E^(-4 t) + 4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t), 6 E^(-8 t) - 30 E^(-7 t) + 55 E^(-6 t) - 42 E^(-5 t) + 9 E^(-4 t) + 3 E^(-2 t)} // Differences // Evaluate  , {t, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Blue}, Green}, PlotLegends -> Placed[    LineLegend[{"f1", "f2", "f3"} // Differences     , LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.81, 0.41}]]

Use Manipulate with an InvervalSlider to change the Plot interval.
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 Plot[{
   4 E^(-8 t) - 18 E^(-7 t) + 27 E^(-6 t) - 10 E^(-5 t) - 9 E^(-4 t) + 
    4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t),
   2 E^(-8 t) - 10 E^(-7 t) + 15 E^(-6 t) - 2 E^(-5 t) - 11 E^(-4 t) + 
    4 E^(-3 t) + 3 E^(-2 t),
   6 E^(-8 t) - 30 E^(-7 t) + 55 E^(-6 t) - 42 E^(-5 t) + 9 E^(-4 t) + 
    3 E^(-2 t)},
  {t, interval[[1]], interval[[2]]},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Blue}, Green}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[
    LineLegend[Subscript[f, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3},
     LegendFunction -> "Panel"],
    {0.88, 0.83}]],
 {{interval, {0.8, 1.2}}, 0, 3, 0.025,
  Appearance -> "Labeled",
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
  Method -> "Push",
  MinIntervalSize -> 0.025},
 TrackedSymbols :> {interval}]


